# How can I reduce Pyinstaller build time of a Python project?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am having a Python project with multiple source packages/files which also uses packages such as **numpy,scipy, pandas**. 
Also I am using **Pyinstaller onefile** mode to package the project in to a single executable and I am trying to reduce the t**ime consumed by Pyinstaller to generate the executable**. 
Firstly Pyinstaller took ~20 minutes to bundle, and most of the time was taken by hook of *"gevent"* module. I excluded gevent module (since it wasn't a truly used module) which bought the time to 8-10 minutes. 
I also notice that by first generating and saving the **"Analysis.toc"** file in build directory can reduce the time taken in Analysis stage in consecutive runs (given that no additional sources were added after first run). 
What are the systematic ways to reduce the pyinstaller's packaging time ? Is saving once generated **Analysis.tc** file and re-use it is safe enough ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a venv using `python -m venv <env_name>` it is especially required for pyinstaller projects that it doesn't bundle the addtional optional modules which you may not need but are installed on your system. This will reduce you file size along with the time required to bundle your app. This is an important step for your purpose.

Second create the spec file using the command `pyi-makespec options name.py`. Take a look at the specfile which is generated which will be named `name.spec` and ensure all required modules are added and unwanted modules are not included and save it.

Once you have your specfile as required, you can make your app as many times are required using the command `pyinstaller options name.spec`